# Margin overflowing on posts with lots of options

Tags: bug, questions, design

Picture is worth 1000 words:
[image]

See the background behind my name is overflowing into the tags section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the SEModifications userscript you're using.  It is something we need to fix in that.

The added timeline and history links are pushing the user signatures over when there is an editor.

Comment: This is probably why I think it's a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange is not responsible if you add userscripts that break layout (evidenced by the timeline and history links).

[See Meta.English.SE for more detail](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/809/).